# Passing Parameter From One Method To Another

Tags: java, jsf, parameter-passing

I have a rather silly question, I need to pass a parameter from one method to another method.
I have the following method

```
public String test(Employees emp)
{
   return emp.getempno();
}
```

I need to pass `emp.getempno()` to my another method `loadDetails();`

My problem is I cannot add an argument in loadDetails() method because I am calling this method in couple of other places.

How can I achieve this? I tried putting `emp.getempno()` in collecion object but problem is `test(Employees emp)` methood is not being invoked in my second method.

Excuse me for my ignorance, any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Update 1

This is how I assign value to test method and getTestValues method is being called from another class when I pass parameter from one page to another.

```
public void getTestValues(List<Employees> paramList)  {
    for (Employees dataItem: paramList) {
        test(dataItem);
    }
}
```

Update 2

This is my loadDetails() method where I am fetching db values and to display as datatable in jsf page.

```
private void loadDetails() {

        try {

            dataDetails = anotherclass.deptDetails(passempno);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("error from loadDetails" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: What class is loadDetails in? Let's see some of that class.

Comment: @Polappan:  It would help if you gave a bit more of the code.  This should be straightforward to resolve, but need a bit more insight into what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Polappan: OK, supposing you had the result of `getempno()` inside `loadDetails()`... what do you want to do with it?  Can you show us what Update 2 looks like with new logic that uses an employee number (assuming we can get it inside?)

Comment: @andersoj Extremely sorry that I forgot to add an argument, I have corrected in Update 2. I would like to pass the empno as an argument to my method in another class.

Comment: What's the functional requirement? You're definitely going the wrong way about this.

Comment: @BalusC Basically what I am trying to do is when I click a row in a datatable I would like to pass that row's primary key to second page's bean class so that I could populate datatable in second page. So I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not!

Comment: JSF 1.2 or 2.x? Do you want to pass it as POST or GET parameter?

Comment: JSF 1.1 and would like to pass as POST

Comment: 1.1? Ahhww.. Commandbutton or commandlink in datatable?

Comment: Unfortunately 1.1. commandlink in datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Basically what I am trying to do is when I click a row in a datatable I would like to pass that row's primary key to second page's bean class so that I could populate datatable in second page.*
>
> *JSF 1.1 and would like to pass as <strike>POST</strike> GET with <strike>commandlink</strike> outputlink in datatable.*

Use the following (assuming JSF 1.1):

`EmployeeBacking`

```
public class EmployeeBacking {

    private List<Employee> list;

    public EmployeeBacking() {
        list = employeeService.list();
    }

    // ...
}
```

`employees.jsp`

```
<h:dataTable value="#{employeeBacking.list}" var="employee">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{employee.name}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputLink value="departments.jsp">
            <h:outputText value="Show departments" />
            <f:param name="employeeId" value="#{employee.id}" />
        </h:outputLink>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

`DepartmentBacking`

```
public class DepartmentBacking {

    private Long employeeId;
    private List<Department> list;

    private void load() {
        list = departmentService.list(employeeId);
    }

    public List<Department> getList() {
        if (list == null) load();
        return list;
    }

    // ...
}
```

*(please note the lazy loading in getter, in JSF 1.2 you could better use `@PostConstruct` method for this)*

`departments.jsp`

```
<h:dataTable value="#{departmentBacking.list}" var="department">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{department.name}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

`faces-config.xml`

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>employeeBacking</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.EmployeeBacking</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>departmentBacking</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.DepartmentBacking</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>employeeId</property-name>
        <value>#{param.employeeId}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

What happens here, the outputlink will navigate to `departments.jsp` with the current employee ID as request parameter and the `<managed-property>` in `faces-config.xml` will set it in the department backing and finally the getter on the list will lazily load the right departments based on the employee ID.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the input to pass parameter from one jsf to another jsp page. However I have one problem with <redirect> in faces-config.xml. If I add <redirect> then employeeId is always null in DepartmentBacking bean. If I remove <redirect> then employeeId is correctly passed. I need to have <redirect> in faces-config.xml. What could be the reason for this and how could I make this work. Thanks

Comment: The reason is because a redirect fires a new request. To make it to work (in JSF 1.1) you'll have to grab the session scope.

Comment: @BalusC You mean I need to put the value in a HTTP session object or change the scope of the bean from request to session?

Comment: Oh wait, after all, you want a HTTP GET request, not a HTTP POST request. Thus replace `<h:commandLink>` by `<h:outputLink>` and remove the entire `<navigation-case>` since it's superfluous.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks a lot, much appreciated. That worked like a charm. is this due to older version of JSF1.1? Besides I need redirect, other my icefaces pages would behave weirdly.

Comment: You're welcome. No this is after all not due to the older version, but due to your poor definition/explanation of the functional requirement.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this, but I think it's becoming a bit clearer.  In order to make `loadDetails()` function properly, you need to know an employee number (shown above in `passempno`).  I have two responses:

1. Best case, it appears that `passempno` is *really* a parameter of the `loadDetails()` method.  I.e., the value of `passempno` is part of the method's behavior.  As such, the strongly preferred option is to simply add the employee number as an argument.  You state that you don't want to do this because other places are using it -- how are the other clients of the method using it without having an employee number specified?
2. If this is part of some non-trivial state of the parent class, then *possibly* you need to sock away the employee number in a field of the object.  This is less than desirable because it's hiding (or at least making implicit) important state that `loadDetails()` needs to function.
3. If there is a stateful interaction with the backing database, and the employee number here is a piece of that state, I'd recommend factoring out the state of the database interaction into a subsidiary class that holds the employee number and any other state (as suggested in 2 above).

Let me know if this helps; if not... let me know what I missed.

Comment: loadDetails() method is called in constructor of the class to load the values when jsf page is called. So I add add an argument in loadDetails() method, it would be a problem when I call the method in constructor.  Basically what I am trying to do is when I click a row in a datatable I would like to pass that row's primary key to second page's bean class so that I could populate datatable in second page.

Comment: @Polappan:  I guess what I'm trying to wrap my head around is whether or not you need that value to call `loadDetails()`.  If you DO need it, then you need it in the constructor, one way or the other.  If what you have is two different flavors of `loadDetails()`, one which needs the param and one which does not, then maybe you need two separate methods...

Answer (score 0):

I work on an ERP software for a living. Your LoadDetails method shouldn't take an Employee as a parameter.

I'm assuming loadDetails is on a Load class, and that you have an Employee who scheduled the load, or filled the load. If that's the case, the Load class should have a reference to that Employee from creation time.

Comment: What does that have to do with `loadDetails()`? Let's see `loadDetails()` so we can figure out how to get Employees inside it.